# How to "instantiate" angular service provider as early as possible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

I have successfully implemented most of what is described here.
https://github.com/colthreepv/angular-login-example

My issue now is that the stateChangeStart event-handler in my login service does not seem to be registered yet when my grandfather resolve executes. The event handler never fires when I initially load the page, it only fires when I change state again after loading the first state. This makes me thing that my resolve is being executed before the stateChangeStart handler in my login-service has been registered. What can I do to make sure the event handlers has been registered when my root state resolve executes?

The global app route and the resolve:

```
.state('app', {
                    abstract: true,
                    templateUrl: 'vassets/partials/partial-nav.html',
                    resolve: {
                        'login': ['loginService','$q', '$http', function (loginService, $q, $http) {
                            loginService.pendingStateChange;
                            var roleDefined = $q.defer();

                            /**
                             * In case there is a pendingStateChange means the user requested a $state,
                             * but we don't know yet user's userRole.
                             *
                             * Calling resolvePendingState makes the loginService retrieve his userRole remotely.
                             */
                            if (loginService.pendingStateChange) {
                                return loginService.resolvePendingState($http.get('/session'));
                            } else {
                                roleDefined.resolve();
                            }
                            return roleDefined.promise;
                        }]
                    }
                })
```

My login-service looks like this (the handlers are setup by the managePermissions() call at the bottom of the service):

```
/*global define */

'use strict';
define(['angular'], function(angular) {

/* Services */
angular.module('myApp.services', [])
        .provider('loginService', function () {
            var userToken = localStorage.getItem('userToken'),
                errorState = 'app.error',
                logoutState = 'app.home';
        this.$get = function ($rootScope, $http, $q, $state, AUTH_EVENTS) {

            /**
             * Low-level, private functions.
             */

            var managePermissions = function () {
                // Register routing function.
                $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {

                   if (wrappedService.userRole === null) {
                        wrappedService.doneLoading = false;
                        wrappedService.pendingStateChange = {
                            to: to,
                            toParams: toParams
                        };
                        return;
                    }

                    if (to.accessLevel === undefined || to.accessLevel.bitMask & wrappedService.userRole.bitMask) {
                        angular.noop(); // requested state can be transitioned to.
                    } else {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $rootScope.$emit('$statePermissionError');
                        $state.go(errorState, { error: 'unauthorized' }, { location: false, inherit: false });
                    }
                });

            };

            /**
             * High level, public methods
             */
            var wrappedService = {
                loginHandler: function (data, status, headers, config) {

                        // update user
                        angular.extend(wrappedService.user, data.user);

                        wrappedService.isLogged = true;

                    wrappedService.userRole = data.user.roles[0].roleName;


                    $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess);
                    $rootScope.currentUser = data.user;

                    return data.user;
                },
                loginUser: function (httpPromise) {
                    httpPromise.success(this.loginHandler);
                },
                resolvePendingState: function (httpPromise) {
                    var checkUser = $q.defer(),
                        self = this,
                        pendingState = self.pendingStateChange;

                    httpPromise.success(
                        function success(httpObj) {
                            if (!httpObj.user) {
                                getLoginData();
                            }
                            else {
                                self.loginHandler(httpObj);
                            }
                        }
                    );

                    httpPromise.then(
                        function success(httpObj) {
                            self.doneLoading = true;
                            if (pendingState.to.accessLevel === undefined || pendingState.to.accessLevel.bitMask & self.userRole.bitMask) {
                                checkUser.resolve();
                            } else {
                                checkUser.reject('unauthorized');
                            }
                        },
                        function reject(httpObj) {
                            checkUser.reject(httpObj.status.toString());
                        }
                    );

                    self.pendingStateChange = null;
                    return checkUser.promise;
                },
                /**
                 * Public properties
                 */
                userRole: null,
                user: {},
                isLogged: null,
                pendingStateChange: null,
                doneLoading: null
            };

                managePermissions();

            return wrappedService;
        };
    })


});
```

Comment: *Waaaay* too much code... reduce your example significantly - remove anything that you does not apply or relevant to the question

Comment: I have removed pretty much code now. Still too much?